# Windows 7 Firewall configuration

Tags: windows-7, networking, vpn, firewall, windows-firewall

I had a PC set up with a VPN. I used the Windows 7 firewall to block all NON-VPN traffic to the internet, but all LAN traffic was allowed. So, with the VPN connected I could connect to all networked machines and the internet. Without the VPN connected I could only connect to the LAN and had no internet access.

Unfortunately my drive failed, and I'm setting up the machine again with a replacement drive. I can't for the life of me work out how to set up the firewall again.

I can easily set it up to block all NON-VPN traffic, but can't work out how to that and still allow all LAN traffic whether the VPN is connected or not.

Some pointers would be useful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've worked it out now.

1. Ensure your LAN is set as a 'Home' network, and your VPN is set as 'Public'
2. Add a new outbound rule.
3. Select Port, Next.
4. Add the following string to the ports "0-46,48-49,51-499,501-1722,1724-4499,4501-65535". This allows the VPN to connect through the LAN, but nothing else. Next.
5. Select "Block the connection". Next.
6. Untick 'Public'. As the VPN is our public connection, and we want to allow everything through that. Next.
7. Give your new rule a name. Next.
8. Right click on new your rule and select "Properties"
9. Select the "Scope" tab.
10. Under "Remote IP address" select "These IP addresses:" and click Add.
11. Assuming your LAN is in the 192.xxx range - Select "This IP address range:" and enter from "0.0.0.0" to "191.255.255.255". Click OK and add another range from "193.0.0.0" to "255.255.255.255". Click OK again.
12. Click OK, Job done!